# How to integrate when zero is in denominator?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I have this equation:

$$(p_0 p_1)'=\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'$$

where $'$ is derivative $\dfrac{d}{dz}$.

I need to solve it (find $p_1$) for case when $r=1$ (I already know $p_0$),  and I don't know what to do because in that case I will have zero in denominator. I can make this shape:

$$(r^2-1)(p_0 p_1)'=4p_0'$$
where I will have zero on left side and just $p_0'$ on the right side, but this equation is part of the system, where I already found solution for $p_0$.

Can you tell me please do you see any solution of this?
$$ $$
Before upper equation it was necessary to solve this one:

$$4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\dfrac{\partial p_1}{\partial z}$$

where $\beta$ is constant, $p=f(z)$, $r$ is radial coordinate, $z$ is longitudinal coordinate and $u=u(r,z)$ and with additional conditions:

$r=0: \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=0$;

$r=1: u=0$.

I got solution: $$
u(r,z)=\frac1{16\beta}\,(r^2-1)\,\frac{dp_1}{dz}(z). 
$$ from this equation is my part in upper equation $(r^2-1)$.

Because first equation is probably not correct because zero in denominator, can you tell me please did I make mistake in solution for $u(r,z)$?

Comment: If $r=1$ you have to put this value $r=1$ into the original system of equations, before coming to $(p_0 p_1)'=\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'$. This will lead to a different equation. Since you didn't show your preliminary calculus one cannot help you.

Comment: I added preliminary calculus in comment.

Comment: $p$ is pressure in different approximations from perturbation theory, in this case of fluid flow.

Comment: @nick_name : You still didn't add the preliminary calculus, before $(p_0 p_1)'=\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'$ The key point is here.

Comment: Ok, but I have half of my notebook of preliminary calculus, and I am not sure in part which I posted, I don't know how to extract some part?

Comment: @nick_name : I understand that. But in the case $r=1$ you cannot obtain an equation such as $(p_0 p_1)'=\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'$. Thus there is a mistake in your notebook of preliminary calculus in the case $r=1$. Or there is a misunderstanding of the original system of equations in this particular case. So, one cannot help you about an unknown calculus.

Comment: The problem here is that you are asking about your approach to some underlying problem without adding any details about what this problem is. How can we be sure the problem is not in your previous steps? Or even what is $p_0$ (does it have a zero at $r=1$)? It's always good to add your approach, but you should if possible always ask about the acctual underlying problem instead of your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $r=1$, the equation $$(p_0p_1)' = \frac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'$$ is meaningless because the right side of the equation is not defined.

The equation $$(r^2-1)(p_0p_1)' = 4p_0'$$ is still meaningfull, however it cannot be used to calculate $p_1$ because the equation is true for any $p_1'$, as long as $p_0$ is a constant function.

Therefore, from only the details written in the question, calculting $p_1$ is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure that I understand why it is cannot be used for $p_1$, but ok. Can you tell me please, part $r^2-1$ I got as part of solution for this differential equation: $$4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial z}$$, where $\beta$ is constant, $p=f(z)$, $r$ is radial coordinate, $z$ is longitudinal coordinate and $u=u(r,z)$ and with additional conditions:

$r=0: \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=0$;

$r=1: u=0$. I got solution: $$
u(r,z)=\frac1{16\beta}\,(r^2-1)\,\frac{dp}{dz}(z). 
$$

Comment: It cannot be used for $p_1$ in the same way as the equation $0\cdot x=y$ cannot be used to calculate $x$. Because so long as $y=0$, the equation $0\cdot x=y$ is true no matter what the value of $x$ is. It's like if I ask you which of the three cars in the parking lot is yours, and you answer "the one with the steering wheel".

Comment: @nick_name Also, please add the detail from your comment *into* the question itself. Don't write details that are crucial to solving the question into the comments.

Comment: I added it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your equation $\quad (p_0 p_1)'=\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'\quad$ is correct :

In case of $r\neq\pm1$
$$p_0 p_1=\int\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'dr+c_1$$
$$p_1(r)=\frac{1}{p_0}\int\dfrac{4}{r^2-1}p_0'dr+\frac{c_1}{p_0}$$
Then, study the limit for $r\to 0$.

Depending on the form of the function $p_0(r)$ , possibly the limit might be finite and then $p_1(0)$ might be significant.